# Magento 2 Widget Condition on edit not display

Tags: magento2, widgets

I am working on the Magento ver. 2.1.7 and added Widget Type **Catalog Product List** in the Home Page Block, with the condition

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

Category  is  6

When I edited this widget again then condition **Category  is  6  is not display** but the result is display fine.

Please guide me.

Comment: Clear cache, upgrade and static content deploy : - Run all these commands , its should work

Comment: @Manoj Deswal, I tried all the commands but no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2913